# How to concisely deal with subsets when their lengths become zero?

Tags: r, subset

To exclude elements from a vector `x`,

```
x <- c(1, 4, 3, 2)
```

we can subtract a vector of positions:

```
excl <- c(2, 3)
x[-excl]
# [1] 1 2
```

This also works dynamically,

```
(excl <- which(x[-which.max(x)] > quantile(x, .25)))
# [1] 2 3
x[-excl]
# [1] 1 2
```

**until** `excl` is of length zero:

```
excl.nolength <- which(x[-which.max(x)] > quantile(x, .95))
length(excl.nolength)
# [1] 0
x[-excl.nolength]
# integer(0)
```

I could kind of reformulate that, but I have many objects to which `excl` is applied, say:

```
letters[1:4][-excl.nolength]
# character(0)
```

I know I could use `setdiff`, but that's rather long and hard to read:

```
x[setdiff(seq(x), excl.nolength)]
# [1] 1 4 3 2

letters[1:4][setdiff(seq(letters[1:4]), excl.nolength)]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Now, I could exploit the fact that nothing is excluded if the element number is greater than the number of elements:

```
length(x)
# [1] 4
x[-5]
# [1] 1 4 3 2
```

To generalize that I should probably use `.Machine$integer.max`:

```
tmp <- which(x[-which.max(x)] > quantile(x, .95))
excl <- if (!length(tmp) == 0) tmp else .Machine$integer.max
x[-excl]
# [1] 1 4 3 2
```

Wrapped into a function,

```
e <- function(x) if (!length(x) == 0) x else .Machine$integer.max
```

that's quite handy and clear:

```
x[-e(excl)]
# [1] 1 2

x[-e(excl.nolength)]
# [1] 1 4 3 2

letters[1:4][-e(excl.nolength)]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

But it seems a little fishy to me...

Is there a better equally concise way to deal with a subset of length zero in base R?

#### Edit

`excl` comes out as dynamic result of a function before (as shown with `which` above) and might be of length zero or not. If `length(excl) == 0` nothing should be excluded. Following lines of code, e.g. `x[-excl]` should not have to be changed at best or as little as possible.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Would you like to return the original vector if everything is excluded in `excl`? This seems rather counter intuitive for most purposes, where you would likely be looking at an early exit instead. `if(length(excl <- ....) == length(x)) stop('Excluding every element')`

Comment: @Oliver Clarified in edit, thanks!

Comment: Not nicer than your solution ...  `x[-c(.Machine$integer.max, excl.nolength)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite `[` with your own function.

```
"["  <- function(x,y) {if(length(y)==0) x else .Primitive("[")(x,y)}

x <- c(1, 4, 3, 2)
excl <- c(2, 3)
x[-excl]
#[1] 1 2
excl <- integer()
x[-excl]
#[1] 1 4 3 2

rm("[") #Go back to normal mode
```

Comment: This is smart, not sure if I'll use it though :)

Comment: @jay.sf I would not use it, but you wrote that `x[-excl]` should not have to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue this is somewhat opinion based.

For example i find:

```
x <- x[-if(length(excl <- which(x[-which.max(x)] > quantile(x, .95))) == 0) .Machine$integer.max else excl]
```

very unreadable, but some people like one-liners. Reading package code you'll often find this is instead split up into one of the many suggestions you gave

```
excl <- which(x[-which.max(x)] > quantile(x, .95))
if(length(excl) != 0)
    x <- x[-excl]
```

Alternatively, you could avoid `which`, and simply use the logical vector for subsetting, and this would likely be considered more clean by most

```
x <- x[!x[-which.max(x)] > quantile(x, .95)]
```

This would avoid zero-length index problem, at the cost of some loss of efficiency.

As a side note, the very example used above and in the question seems somewhat off. First `which.max` only returns the first index which is equal to the max value, and in addition the index will be offset for every value removed. More likely the expected example would be

```
x <- x[!(x > quantile(x, .95))[-which(x == max(x))]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How bout this?

```
a <- letters[1:3]
excl1 <- c(1,3)
excl2 <- c()

a[!(seq_along(a) %in% excl1)]
a[!(seq_along(a) %in% excl2)]
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's similar to `setdiff(seq(x), excl)` above and rather hard to read as said.