# What is the best way to filter a df without return null when filter command is repeated?

Tags: r

I'm trying to delete rows of a data frame by values in a column and I want that, when triggered the command again, it doesn't return null. By example:

```
df<-data.frame(
   num=c(6,7,6,7,3,4,2,6,5),
   typ=c("A","A","B","A","B","A","B",NA,NA)
 )
 df
  num  typ
1   6    A
2   7    A
3   6    B
4   7    A
5   3    B
6   4    A
7   2    B
8   6 <NA>
9   5 <NA>

df1 <- df[-which(df$typ=="A"&df$num>5),]
df1
  num  typ
3   6    B
5   3    B
6   4    A
7   2    B
8   6 <NA>
9   5 <NA>

df2 <- df1[-which(df1$typ=="A"&df1$num>5),]
df2
[1] num typ
<0 linhas> (ou row.names de comprimento 0)
```

In `df1` the df was filtered by the first time and returned the right answer. In `df2`, however, triggering the command again returns 0 rows. Using `subset` has another trouble:

```
df1_s <- subset(df,!(df$typ=="A" & df$num>5))
df1_s
  num  typ
3   6    B
5   3    B
6   4    A
7   2    B
9   5 <NA>

df2_s <- subset(df1_s,!(df1_s == "A" & df1_s$num>5))
df2_s
     num  typ
3      6    B
5      3    B
6      4    A
7      2    B
9      5 <NA>
NA    NA <NA>
NA.1  NA <NA>
NA.2  NA <NA>
NA.3  NA <NA>
NA.4  NA <NA>
```

Look that in `df1_s` the eighth line was incorrectly omissed, and some strange things happen in `df2_s`. It is really necessary that the command could be triggered twice or more.

I appreciate any help and I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: Have a look at [How to concisely deal with subsets when their lengths become zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59406950/10488504)

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand. What's wrong in doing a filtering with `typ != "A" | num < 5`? Your syntax is a bit cumbersome. Can you confirm that you just want rows 3, 5, 6 and 7 without row 9 which contains a `NA`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You expect that `df[-0,]` returns `df`, what is not the case. It returns an empty `data.frame`. A dirty trick is to `c` `.Machine$integer.max`.

```
(df1 <- df[-c(.Machine$integer.max, which(df$typ=="A"&df$num>5)),])
#  num  typ
#3   6    B
#5   3    B
#6   4    A
#7   2    B
#8   6 <NA>
#9   5 <NA>
(df2 <- df1[-c(.Machine$integer.max, which(df1$typ=="A"&df1$num>5)),])
#  num  typ
#3   6    B
#5   3    B
#6   4    A
#7   2    B
#8   6 <NA>
#9   5 <NA>
```

A nicer solution test the length of the subset:

```
i <- which(df$typ=="A"&df$num>5)
(df1 <- if(length(i)==0) df1 else df[-i,])
#  num  typ
#3   6    B
#5   3    B
#6   4    A
#7   2    B
#8   6 <NA>
#9   5 <NA>
i <- which(df1$typ=="A"&df1$num>5)
(df2 <- if(length(i)==0) df1 else df1[-i,])
#  num  typ
#3   6    B
#5   3    B
#6   4    A
#7   2    B
#8   6 <NA>
#9   5 <NA>
```

In case you are working with logical vector you have to test for `NA`.

```
i <- !(df$typ=="A" & df$num>5)
(df1 <- df[is.na(i) | i,])
#  num  typ
#3   6    B
#5   3    B
#6   4    A
#7   2    B
#8   6 <NA>
#9   5 <NA>
i <- !(df1$typ=="A" & df1$num>5)
(df2 <- df1[is.na(i) | i,])
#  num  typ
#3   6    B
#5   3    B
#6   4    A
#7   2    B
#8   6 <NA>
#9   5 <NA>
```